# How to reduce this jquery toggle code for an image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out how to reduce this code down! it basically hides an image then show a div depending on what image map area is clicked!

I have a code pen of a working demo here: http://codepen.io/naniio/pen/wBExYq

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".auckland").click(function() {
        $(".map").toggle();
        $("#aukl.hide").toggle();
    });

    $(".gisborne").click(function() {
        $(".map").toggle();
        $("#gisb.hide").toggle();
    });

    $(".wellington").click(function() {
        $(".map").toggle();
        $("#well.hide").toggle();
    });

    $(".nelson").click(function() {
        $(".map").toggle();
        $("#nel.hide").toggle();
    });

    $(".christchurch").click(function() {
        $(".map").toggle();
        $("#chch.hide").toggle();
    });

    $(".queenstown").click(function() {
        $(".map").toggle();
        $("#queen.hide").toggle();
    });

    $(".otago").click(function() {
        $(".map").toggle();
        $("#ota.hide").toggle();
    });
});
```

I have tried using find and other jquery methods but I must be looking in the wrong places

Any help would be great I'm new to jQuery but not new to stack overflow I can imagine this is an easy question/fix for some and this may be rated harshly or ignored! but for those who continually help this community regardless, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something working in this pen. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByOEam
Just add an extra attribute in the area tags

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clickable").click(function() {
       var toHide = $(this).attr('data-hide');
        $(".map").toggle();
        $("#"+toHide).toggle();
    });

    $(".hide").click(function() {
      $(".map").toggle();
      $(this).toggle();
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

A little refactoring to `<area>` tags like this

```
<area shape="circle" coords="220,97,15" alt="Auckland" title="Auckland" href="#" data-ref="aukl.hide">
```

would cleanup your html from unnecessary classes and would give you cleaner javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("map area").click(function() {
        $(".map").toggle();
        $("#" + this.data("ref")).toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class to the all the div that will be clicked, say "`lands`", and use following code,

```
$(".lands").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".map").toggle();
    $this.toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this reduced jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').on('click',function(){
      $(".map").toggle();
      $(this).toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you need to add the same behavior to many different objects probably a good pattern is to use a function and dynamic creation.

For example in your specific case I'd expect to have

- An image with the map (without dots)
- A list of locations (possibly retrieved from a DB)
- Code that for each of the locations creates the dot image correctly positioned on the map

Something like:

```
function addLocation(x, y, name, data) {
    var dot = document.createElement("img");
    dot.className = "dot";
    dot.onload = function() {
        // x,y coordinates are relative to map size to account
        // for responsive designs
        dot.left = (x*mapContainer.offsetWidth - dot.offsetWidth/2) + "px";
        dot.top = (y*mapContainer.offsetHeight - dot.offsetHeight/2) + "px";
        mapContainer.appendChild(dot);
    };
    dot.src = "dot.png";
    dot.onclick = function() {
        showMap(name, data);
    };
}
```

This way adding/changing a location only requires updating the database (or the static data array if using a database is not worth at the moment).

Adding by hand location names and chart names (that are random small variations one of the other like `gisborne->gisb` but `christchurch->chch`) is a step toward making the page a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: While I agree on maintenance point I do not see how storing presentation data like coordinates in DB will be any better that hard-coding it into presentation itself. None of the answers here provide solution for responsive / adaptive design (using different size images) and all of the answers stick to the original size of the image. In general your point is valid but in this particular case I'd say it's over-engineering

Comment: @Ramunas: I'm not sure what do you mean by over-engineering; even for just 4 locations probably a dynamic creation solutions requires LESS code (and code that is quite trivial). Coordinates could be scaled for handling responsive designs (just use `x*mapContainer.offsetWidth` instead of bare `x` and make `x`, `y` to be relative to map size).

Comment: Well, extra table in DB, ORM, DAL, BLL, MVC/WebAPI (or whatever project structure you use in backend) and probably extra ajax call just to get locations of 4-5 cities on one particular image? For me it's over-engineering for this trivial situation. If it were all countries we talk about then sure it's another type of problem where I say _In general your point is valid_. And responsive/adaptive does not necessary mean scaling.

Comment: @Ramunas: That's why I said "possibly". Even without a database in my opinion the best solution is to use dynamic creation and an array for the data instead of hand-coding the result.